# Primefaces with Mongo DB Demo application?

Tags: mongodb, jsf-2, primefaces

As per **Primefaces** their component well supported by **JSON** Object so its possible to use **MongoDB** with **Primefaces** application .Any one know how can i use **MongoDB** in place of **Postgresql** which currently i am using

Comment: Subodh, have you tried installing them both and at least trying to integrate them on your own. You know that database and view/presentation are different layers of an application that can be independent, like switch DAO and that's it. Next, JSF/PF is a component-based web framework that doesn't expose too much JS at your command. Finally, I'd suppose MongoDB fits better a JavaScript MVC framework. I'm voting to close.

Comment: You need to consider JSP instead of JSF in this case. Therefore PF or any other JSF component suits are out of the question here. If you need UI components for your view there are excellent choices such as Jquery UI and/or Jquery Mobile UI. Compared to JSF/PF Jquery Mobile UI can do a very good job combined with JSON and JAX-RS.